# How to get Conan/CMake to give me debugging information to find a segfault

Tags: c++, cmake, segmentation-fault, conan

I need to debug a segfault. I'm using Conan (`conan build ..`) to compile. I added this to CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
```

But, when I run the binary and get the segfault I just get

```
Segmentation fault
ERROR: conanfile.py: Error in build() method, line 15
        self.run("bin/main")
        ConanException: Error 139 while executing bin/main
```

I have also tried this in conanfile.py in the build step

```
cmake.definitions["CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE"] = "Debug"
```

What should I do to get information about why I'm getting a segfault?

Comment: In general it is better to avoid defining the build type in CMakeLists.txt code like set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug"). Conan will define it in the toolchain if necessary, or pass it in command line with ``-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE``, depending on the generator. For multi-config generators, it is important to build with the same type in ``cmake --build . --config Debug``. In general it would be useful to have more information about your system: OS, compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot configure conan to "get debug information".

For ad hoc debugging, I would recommend to run the program inside a debugger manually.

However, what you could do is configure your operating system to produce a core dump of the program upon segfault. That way you can let conan execute the program without a debugger, and inspect the memory dump using a debugger afterwards.

That said, seeing the state of the program as you can with a memory dump, dosen't necessarily tell everything, and debuggning step by step can show too much information and finding the bug can be difficult. One good tool is to build the program with undefined behaviour and address sanitizers and hope that they catch the bug.